# Facebook share doesn't fetch meta properties

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, sharethis

I am creating a website with the WordPress tool. Here is the link : http://ati.ismt.pt/wordpress/

Before the last WordPress update I was able to have this working, but now, sharing a post via facebook is getting default setting information from the post, instead of the info I want it to share. I can't even get the image fetched.

I am using a plug-in called ShareThis, and here is my head.php code:

```
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object#">

<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post-  >ID)); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ati.ismt.pt/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/ismtLogo2.jpg" />
```

I have already checked my og protocol markup trough this checker : http://ogp.spypixel.com/Pogo/checker/index.php

Everything looks fine, no errors. I'm in need of some help and any kind of it will be wellcome.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fati.ismt.pt%2Fwordpress%2F, http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fati.ismt.pt%2Fwordpress%2F%3Fp%3D76